# How to load data from PHP after page load

Tags: php

This is my dashboard.

I am getting data to this page using API. This is a small part of this page and it takes a long time to load.

[image: page content]

It takes 10 seconds for all the data to be loaded through the API.
The functions themselves look like this

```
$YMAPIusers = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits,ym:s:newUsers,ym:s:bounceRate,ym:s:pageDepth,ym:s:avgVisitDurationSeconds,ym:s:sumGoalReachesAny', $dimensionsYMAPI = null, 'today', 'today');
$YMAPIpages = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:pv:pageviews,ym:pv:users', 'ym:pv:URLHash', 'today', 'today');
$YMAPIvisits = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits', 'ym:s:searchPhrase', 'today', 'today');
$YMAPIuserdata = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:pv:users', 'ym:pv:deviceCategory', 'today', 'today');
$YMAPI_user_age = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits', 'ym:s:ageInterval', 'today', 'today');
$YMAPI_source = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits', 'ym:s:lastsignTrafficSource', 'today', 'today');
```

This way i insert data into the page

```
<?= $YMAPIusers['totals'][0][0] ?>
```

Can you please tell me how can I load the page first, and then dynamically load the data? Based on my example please

I tried this

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:'/main/index.php',
        data:"YMAPI_call=true", 
        success: function(data){
            alert('successful');
        }   
    });
};
```

and

```
if(isset($_GET['YMAPI_call'])){
    $YMAPIusers = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits,ym:s:newUsers,ym:s:bounceRate,ym:s:pageDepth,ym:s:avgVisitDurationSeconds,ym:s:sumGoalReachesAny', $dimensionsYMAPI = null, 'today', 'today');
    $YMAPIpages = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:pv:pageviews,ym:pv:users', 'ym:pv:URLHash', 'today', 'today');
    $YMAPIvisits = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits', 'ym:s:searchPhrase', 'today', 'today');
    $YMAPIuserdata = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:pv:users', 'ym:pv:deviceCategory', 'today', 'today');
    $YMAPI_user_age = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits', 'ym:s:ageInterval', 'today', 'today');
    $YMAPI_source = YMAPI($countersYMAPI[0], $tokenYMAPI, 'ym:s:visits', 'ym:s:lastsignTrafficSource', 'today', 'today');
}
```

and

```
<?= isset($YMAPIusers['totals'][0][0]) ?>
```

I found this solution online but nothing worked for me

My php api call

```
function YMAPI($countersYMAPI, $tokenYMAPI, $metricsYMAPI, $dimensionsYMAPI = null ,$date1YMAPI, $date2YMAPI){
$params = array(
    'ids'     => "$countersYMAPI[counter]", 
    'metrics' => $metricsYMAPI,
    'dimensions' => $dimensionsYMAPI,
    'date1'   => $date1YMAPI,
    'date2'   => $date2YMAPI,
);

$ch = curl_init('https://api-metrika.yandex.net/stat/v1/data/bytime?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: OAuth ' . $tokenYMAPI));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
global $resYMAPI;
$resYMAPI = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$resYMAPI = json_decode($resYMAPI, true);

return $resYMAPI;
}
```

how can i do it in JS and insert data into my page?

Comment: Use javascript to do ajax calls for retrieving the data.

Comment: Can we tell you how? no, Can we point you in the right direction, yes: You need an ajax call in javascript.

Comment: tried it, it didn't work out for me. that's why I came here for help

Comment: Then show us what you tried, and give a proper problem description along with it. Every answer you get will only be "use AJAX" again - that _is_ the right way.

Comment: ok, understood, thanks, now I will add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will need it.

Connecting to the Yandex Metrics API using JS

I decided to connect to the API via Fetch ().

Example with headers below

```
async function API_get_data() {
     let API_data = await fetch(
         'https://api-metrika.yandex.net/stat/v1/data/bytime?ids={id-counter}&metrics={metrics}&dimensions={dimensions}&date1={date1}&date2={date2}',
          {
               headers: {
                    "Authorization": "OAuth {your-token}"
               } 
          }
     )
 }
```